# Serializing a list

Tags: c#, xml

I have a `ColorFormat` class that contains a string format for a color and its format name. In the software, I will define multiple instances of this class and regroup all of them in the class ColorFormats:

```
[XmlRoot("ColorFormats")] 
public class ColorFormats : Collection<ColorFormat> // <-- Notice ColorFormat
{
    private static ColorFormats m_collection = new ColorFormats();

    public static ColorFormats Collection
    {
        get { return m_collection; }
        set { m_collection = value; }
    }

    private ColorFormats() { }
}
```

Collection is the global variable I will use to access the list. The main purpose of this class is to be serialized in XML to get:

```
<ColorFormats>
    <ColorFormat Name='Hex Format'>#RGB</ColorFormat>
    <ColorFormat Name='Dec Format'>(R,G,B)</ColorFormat>
</ColorFormats>
```

The code above is working fine, but I was wondering if the approach is good and following standards or if there are better ways of doing it.

Comment: (old naming convention)m_collection => _collection || this.collection

Answer (score 4):

Your class has a private constructor then it can't be derived, make it explicit using `sealed`:

```
public sealed class ColorFormats : Collection<ColorFormat>
```

`m_collection` can't change after it has been initialized (class constructor is private...), be sure about it and mark it as `readonly`:

```
private static readonly ColorFormats m_collection = new ColorFormats();
```

And remove property setter:

```
public static ColorFormats Collection
{
    get { return m_collection; }
}
```

I'd also consider a better name for `ColorFormats.Collection`, something to explain its meaning/usage instead of merely its container.

From this short snippet I can't say more (it may be interesting if you also post `ColorFormat` class in a new question).

However something keeps catching my sight: a singleton is a global variable. More controlled, of course, but still global. Hard to test and a pain to debug because anyone can interact with it (BTW your actual code is not thread-safe then it's caller responsibility.) What are you trying to do here? Can't you avoid this *pattern*?

Note that if, instead, you're doing this only with the purpose of serialization then it's just pretty wrong, use an adapter to serialize a surrogate of your main class, it's pretty fragile to model your domain classes according to your serialization needs (because they will both change independently.)

Comment: Firstly, the aim of this class is to get the xml above(from xml serialization), the only way i've found is to have a class with xmlroot containing the list of ColorFormat. Secondly, I usually declare my global variables in a static class as static, here i've merged everything.

I will amend the full code in the following minutes.

Comment: Having a private constructor in this scenario is not the main issue, as the members of the class were declared static . But i must agree with  your naming  convention is a bit off . @HishamMaudarbocus there are other ways to read XML including XMLDocument class

Comment: To read XML in-code is not a problem, but i am bound to used the proposed format. About the naming, am still thinking of a new one. Anyway i am unable to make edits to my post, it keeps on "loading" when i click edit

Comment: @HishamMaudarbocus please do not misunderstand me, class itself is not _wrong_, what I mean is the singleton (Collection property) is harder to debug and test (because accessed concurrently and static). Pretty often (not always) a singleton is the only solution (reasonable) solution but you may want to explore different designs

Comment: @TolaniJaiye-Tikolo yes, I don't think private constructor is bad (it serves its purpose) but then I'd make it explicit using marking class as sealed and removing setter (hem...what if _someone_ writes null?)